# Xamarin Syncfusion chart not displaying binding data from local database

Tags: xamarin.forms, charts, syncfusion

I'm trying to pull data from a local database and populate it in a bar or line chart, I've followed every tutorial out there but can't find where I'm going wrong.  The database has data and I can access it with the method App.Database.GetJournalEntries() in other pages and foreach looping through the List, but I can't seem to bind it to the XBindingPath and YBindingPath when I try to use the same list in a chart.

viewData.xaml.cs

```
public ViewData()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        this.Title = "Data";
        InitializeComponent();
        SfChart chart = new SfChart();
        chart.Title.Text = "Chart";

        //Initializing primary axis
        CategoryAxis primaryAxis = new CategoryAxis();
        primaryAxis.Title.Text = "Name";
        chart.PrimaryAxis = primaryAxis;

        //Initializing secondary Axis
        NumericalAxis secondaryAxis = new NumericalAxis();
        secondaryAxis.Title.Text = "Height (in cm)";
        chart.SecondaryAxis = secondaryAxis;

        //Initializing column series
        ColumnSeries series = new ColumnSeries();
        series.ItemsSource = App.Database.GetJournalEntries();
        series.XBindingPath = "entryTitle";
        series.YBindingPath = "emotRange";
        series.Label = "emot";

        series.DataMarker = new ChartDataMarker();
        series.EnableTooltip = true;
        chart.Legend = new ChartLegend();

        chart.Series.Add(series);
        this.Content = chart;
    }
```

Viewmodel

```
public class Database
{
    SQLiteAsyncConnection _database;

    public Database(string dbPath)
    {
        _database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);
        _database.CreateTableAsync<db_GS>().Wait();
    }

     //Method I'm using to pull the data
    public Task<List<db_GS>> GetJournalEntries()
    {
        return _database.Table<db_GS>().ToListAsync();
    }


}
```

Data model

```
public class db_GS
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string entryTitle { get; set; }
    public string entryText { get; set; }
    public string emot { get; set; }
    public float emotRange { get; set; }
    public string dataTime { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `GetJournalEntries` is async, but you are not awaiting it when you assign your ItemsSource.  That's the first obvious issue that I see

Comment: Yep that did it... thank you very much @Jason